# Unable to see Graphs created using Java API in Neo4j browser

Tags: java, neo4j

I have written a Java program to create graphs in Neo4j and I followed the below tutorial. The Java program works perfectly and does create nodes and relationships. I have written another Java program to cross check the data using Java Cypher API.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_native_java_api_example.htm

So, I have below code to create the database:

```
public static File Neo4j_DB = new File("C:/TPNeo4jDB/databases/graph.db");

public static GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();

public static GraphDatabaseService graphDb= 
                                 dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(Neo4j_DB);
```

But I am using Neo4j 3.3 and after downloading the zip version, I do not see Neo4j community edition dialog box that would help me to browse through the database created. So, when I go to http://localhost:7474/browser/, I do not see any data as it is still pointing to the default database. I tried changing the configuration file but it is not working but it seems I am not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `neo4j.conf` file, you need to set these 2 properties appropriately:

- `dbms.directories.data`

  - This must specify a directory path.
  - This path must have a `databases` subdirectory (but that subdirectory must not be included in the `dbms.directories.data` value).
- `dbms.active_database`

  - This must be the directory containing the actual neo4j graph DB (i.e., it contains the indexes and data files).
  - This directory must be a child of the above-mentioned `databases` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question, can you please look at it.

Comment: It looks like you changed your question into a combined question and answer? That is probably not acceptable for StackOverflow questions. Instead, you should probably have just added a comment to my Answer, and then I could modify my Answer. Or, you could add another Answer (to your own question). Also, you do not need to state that a Question is Solved in the title, since an Accepted Answer would indicate that.